# exported to STL on MeshLab is no longer a text file

Tags: c++, cad, meshlab

I have an `.stl` file produced by a scanner with a lot of triangles. I want to use that data to create a hole repair algorithm.  To prepare the data, I want to reduce the amount of vertices.  First, I use the MeshLab "Quadratic decimation" reduction filter. After that, I try to export the mesh as `.stl` but the new file is no longer recognized as a text file. When I open it with notepad++ to check the vertices, I only see strange symbols - but the new file is still recognized by MeshLab.

Is there a way to save the `.stl` file in order to read it as a text file too? If not, how can the non-text format be read from a C++ program?

Answer (score 2):

Just uncheck the "Binary encoding" box inside the export mesh window.